# How do I draw a rectangle that takes up 50% of the device width for an Android UI layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I would like to draw a gray-colored rectangle across 50% of the device's screen width on the UI and have the rectangle centered horizontally.  I am going to embed 2 buttons horizontally in the rectangle for user input.  Is there an easy way to set up the layout for 50% of the screen width?  Use a drawable for the rectangle?

Output based on LinearLayout code recommended below:
[image]

Below is layout file.  Note I had to include layout_width="wrap_content" for both Buttons because Android Studio did not like layout_width="0dp" due to nested layouts warning.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:background="@color/colorHint">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clearButton"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/savebutton_rounded"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClickClear"  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButtonRV"
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/savebutton_rounded"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_save_white_24dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_save_white_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClickSave"  />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do it all in just the layout XML, using a ViewGroup with a gray background for the rectangle, and taking advantage of weights to size things properly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#cccccc">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You didn't specify the height of the gray rectangle, so I assumed you want it to wrap the Buttons.

Comment: Ok so use layout_weight.  2 for the rectangle and 1+1 for the blank space to the left and to the right of the rectangle.  Am I thinking about what you have proposed correctly?  Wrapping the buttons is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds like it. That'll make the rectangle the same width as the two Spaces combined, making it 50% of the total width.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try.  I will check back in an hour to update based on how it goes.

Comment: P.s. would appreciate any comments on the answer below that  recommends using Percent code.  Less code but I don't have any experience using.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that'd work. I hadn't learned of those classes yet. Either solution should work for you. The other answer, though, requires a library, which some people like to avoid. It's up to your personal preference.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to Android, what are the downsides or negatives to using a library?

Comment: Nothing major, really. It does introduce another dependency, and does add code and therefore adds to the app size. In this case, though, it's not gonna be much, I would think (a few kbs, maybe), and Proguard will crunch it pretty well. It's really just up to which way you wanna go.

Comment: Ok, so looks good.  I need a few minor edits.  The two buttons are not centered within the rectangle.  Also, what is difference between "center_vertical" and "center" for the LinearLayout?

Comment: Plain `center` will center in both directions, but in our layout, we don't need to have it center horizontally, hence we use `center_vertical`. You could use `center` in this case, though, to the same effect. As for the Buttons not being centered, I'm not sure what to tell you without seeing your layout. I tested the one I posted, and it was as expected. If you wanna post yours, we can have a look.

Comment: Ok, so for some reason the Button is not just wrapping the text content...it is as tall as the rectangle.  I will upload image above.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you just need to increase the `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom` on your Buttons. You could also adjust the parent LinearLayout's `padding`.

Comment: That works, I need to play around with how much.  I'm surprised the Button took the full width of the rectangle.  I would have thought with "wrap_content" that it would only make the Button height a little bit larger than the size of the Button text, not the full width of the rectangle.

Comment: Yeah, on regular Buttons there's the appropriate margins and paddings set, but I think the `borderlessButtonStyle` you've set on yours is causing that.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your time and assistance.  Answer accepted and upvoted, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout is introduced in support library. It is very neat and you can specify any percentage for any child view.

More information about PercentFrameLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html.

Or PercentRelativeLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

You can use this by importing `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'` in gradle.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't come across those before.  Do you think using your example would be more efficient than a LinearLayout solution using layout_weights like the other answered suggested above.

Comment: Yes it is introduced relatively recently.  I am not sure how efficient but it is more compact and readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Emma Nice. I didn't know about those yet. Thanks for the info!

Comment: :) yup, this was a nice addition to the base ViewGroups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout and weights like Mike suggests, or you can try the percentage support library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
    android:background="#888"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <!-- Your buttons here -->

  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

And remember to `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'` in your build.gradle